# How to take this partial derivative of double integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to understand the derivation in the appendix of the Advantage-Weighted Regression paper (https://openreview.net/attachment?id=H1gdF34FvS&name=original_pdf, page 15)

One of the steps is the following steps (abbreviated to the relevant part of the equations):

$L(\pi)=\int_s d(s) \int_a \pi(a|s)\big[ R_{s,a} - V(s) \big] da ds  $. Here, the $d(s)$ is a distribution in $s$, so $\int_s d(s)ds=1$, and $\pi(a|s)$ is also a conditional distribution of $a$: $\int_a \pi(a|s) da=1 \forall s $.

The authors claim that we can take derivative of the above double integral with respect to the function $\pi(a|s)$ to the following results:

$\cfrac{\delta L}{\delta \pi(a|s)} = d(s) \big(R_{s,a}-V(s)\big)$.

I do not understand the above step. Why did both integral disappear? Is it because $\pi$ is a function of both $s$ and $a$? Could someone help understand this step? Thank you!

Comment: It is probably an abuse of notation. They are using calculus of variations to find the optimal shape of $\pi(a|s)$. As such, they differentiate the integrand, not the integral itself, calculating the variation of the integrand with respect to $\pi(a|s)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your answer. Could you please elaborate for me?

Comment: Consider for example the Euler-Lagrange equation (which is in fact the one they are using) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation. The differentiability is considered on the integrand (which is called Lagrangian), but not on the full integral expression, thanks to the fundamental lemma of the calculus of variations. In broad terms, the integral does not appear in the first-order conditions because you assume that if it is zero, then the integrand is zero everywhere.